# Unable to Open Workspace in RAD

Tags: plugins, crash, rad, workspace

I'm unable to open a workspace in RAD. The get the below message in .log file in .metadata folder in the workspace.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core 2 2 2011-05-10 14:06:16.421  
!MESSAGE A workspace crash was detected. The previous session did not exit normally. Not using saved tag library indexes
```

From the error message I understand there is some issue with the org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core plugin. I removed the plugin from the plugin folder as well. Still the error persist.
I am looking for a solution. Recreating the workspace is NOT an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Colleague suggested removing plugins related to jsp, viz. **org.eclipse.jst**.xxx. I deleted folder with prefix **org.eclipse.jst** and the Workspace opened up. Thanks.